# Report Builder: Expression to find Monday of the current week

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, expression, reportbuilder3.0

I can't figure out how to return the Monday of the current week *using an expression in Report Builder 3.0*. In SQL, it's easy:

`DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)`

I tried converting this to an expression like this:

`=DateAdd("w", datediff("w", 0, now()), 0)`

...but this returned the error: `Argument 'Date1' cannot be converted to type 'Date'`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by getting the current day of the week using `DatePart`, then deducting this number of days from the current date (you need to add 1 since weekdays are 1 based, not 0 based):

```
=DateAdd("d",1 - DatePart("w",Today,FirstDayOfWeek.Monday,FirstWeekOfYear.System),Today)
```

Comment: This returns Sunday, not Monday. I also just need the date, not the time.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the `FirstDayOfWeek` argument, and also to use `Today` instead of `Now` to remove the time